# Iterating over a range to copy formulas to create named ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a simple macro that:

1. copies a formula (in the form of a string) from a range
2. uses the formula (string) to populate a Name for cells in said range

Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim label As String

    Set rng = Sheet2.Range("inputs")

    For Each cell In rng
    
        If _
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = "Ignore me 1" Or _
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = "Ignore me 2" Or _
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = "Ignore me 3" Or _
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = "Ignore me 4" Or _
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = "Ignore me 5" _
        Then 'do nothing
        Else
            label = cell.FormulaR1C1
            ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add name:=label, RefersToR1C1:=cell.FormulaR1C1
            label = ""
        End If
    Next cell


End Sub
```

VB editor is throwing the following: Run-time error: 1004, Application-defined or object defined error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line has the error? are you sure that `label` is always a valid name?

Comment: The error is somewhere in the `Else`; block commenting this removes the error and the code runs successfully.

Comment: A specific line will be highlighted if you click "Debug" when it errors.  I'd guess that the name you're trying to add is not valid, but difficult to be sure with no example values.

Comment: I am thinking that `label` should always be a valid name as long as the cell it's referring to can be empty. Maybe I'm not understanding you second question well enough.

Comment: No Debug option, only "Okay" and "Help" :\

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you're pulling out of the cells in the loop, including a value which shows the error you're describing.

Comment: You're trying to call the name using the FormulaR1C1 value?  I don't think that will work.  The label may have "=" at the start and that alone is not permitted.

Comment: Try setting your VBA error handling (VB editor >> Tools >> Options >> General tab) to "Break in class module"

Comment: Skin and Tim - both very helpful; the line throwing the error is `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add name:=label, RefersToR1C1:=cell.FormulaR1C1`

Comment: What is the value of `label` when it fails?  See here for the naming rules: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/11/excel-name-named-range-define-use/#:~:text=Excel%20naming%20rules&text=An%20Excel%20name%20should%20be,Excel%20will%20throw%20an%20error.

Comment: I made some progress - with `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add name:=label, RefersTo:=cell.Address` I was able to actually get names in the name manager. The problem is, the "Refers To" property in the name manager is filled with `="$B$9"` and I need it to be filled with `=$B$9`. Any idea on how to remove the quotation marks? Should I convert `label` to something else other than string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (assuming the value all non-ignored cells is a valid name)

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim c As Range, v
    For Each c In Sheet2.Range("inputs").Cells
        v = c.value
        Select Case v
            Case "Ignore me 1", "Ignore me 2", "Ignore me 3", _
                 "Ignore me 4", "Ignore me 5"
                'do nothing
            Case Else
                ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add name:=v, _
                                         RefersTo:=c 'no need for .Address()
        End Select
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: This works Tim - the key is treating the variable as a value instead of a formula/string. Thanks Tim!